# Labelling functions in Gadfly plot

Tags: julia, gadfly

Plotting functions directly is easy in Gadfly:

```
plot([sin, cos], 0, 25)
```

This gives my two differently colored lines, automatically labelled in the legend as something like `f_1` and `f_2`:

[image]

How can I change the default names in the "Color" legend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `color` argument to a list of labels:

```
plot([sin, cos], 0, 25, color=["sine", "cosine"])
```

[image: Update labels]

Comment: Ah, and the reason is that it gets converted to a [Geom.line with Stat.func](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/blob/d36d54ea7b9648851d0f0a4d3577b0f813af7e2f/src/poetry.jl#L41). Thanks!